# Lining 3 columns divs when one is removed via css?

Tags: css, html

I have a 3 column layout accross 3 rows. Each div will have a 'user permission' behind it, so only allowing certain users to view the content. What I have been trying to do is have a simple 3 column div layout which when one div is removed will allow the other divs to move into place. However, I'm not having much joy with everything that I'm currently finding!

If anyone has an idea and can assist, I would be very grateful.

I also hope this makes sense!

G.

Comment: Look at bootrstrap grid system.

Comment: I've tried this, but I'm getting the same result. An empty column rather than the div from the other row moving into it's place. :-(

Comment: It seems to be a bad practice to move cols between rows. It's better you to determine cols visibility via your user permission and then redner cols inside one row or inside another, depending on cols count. Another approach with bootstrap - add more columns than max row width (for 3x3 add single row with 9 divs having col-md-4 class for each). And it's better to hide entire column not it's content.